# Error starting MySQL in a MariaDB Galera cluster in CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, cluster, mariadb

I'm trying to setup a MariaDB Galera cluster following **[this](http://www.unixmen.com/setup-mariadb-galera-cluster-10-0-centos/)** tutorial exactly as it is, and I'm stuck in the **Step 7– Initialize the first cluster node**, I'm doing so with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster` and after a while in `Starting MySQL.....`, it ends in `Starting MySQL..... ERROR!`

Can anyone tell me what's happening? This is my MySQL log:

```
150408 11:46:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150408 11:46:56 mysqld_safe WSREP: Running position recovery with --log_error='/var/lib/mysql/wsrep_recovery.X0vkQP' --pid-file='/var/lib/mysql/db1-recover.pid'
150408 11:46:58 mysqld_safe WSREP: Recovered position 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_start_position var submitted: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1'
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 25.3.9(r3385) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using "slicing-by-8" algorithm.
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_host = 172.28.109.10; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false; pc.ignore_quorum = false; pc.ignore_sb = false; pc.npvo = false; pc.recove
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: 'wsrep-new-cluster' option used, bootstrapping the cluster
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
150408 11:46:58 [Warning] WSREP: access file(gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: (7dc963a0, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: (7dc963a0, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: bootstrapping new group 'galera_cluster'
150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: start_prim is enabled, turn off pc_recovery
150408 11:46:58 [ERROR] WSREP: Permission denied
150408 11:46:58 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 13: error while trying to listen 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567?socket.non_blocking=1', asio error 'Permission denied': 13 (Permission denied)
     at gcomm/src/asio_tcp.cpp:listen():777
150408 11:46:58 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:long int gcs_core_open(gcs_core_t*, const char*, const char*, bool)():206: Failed to open backend connection: -13 (Permission denied)
150408 11:46:58 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:long int gcs_open(gcs_conn_t*, const char*, const char*, bool)():1379: Failed to open channel 'galera_cluster' at 'gcomm://172.28.109.10,172.28.109.11,172.28.109.12': -13 (Permission denied)
150408 11:46:58 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Permission denied
150408 11:46:58 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect() failed: 7
150408 11:46:58 [ERROR] Aborting

150408 11:46:58 [Note] WSREP: Service disconnected.
150408 11:46:59 [Note] WSREP: Some threads may fail to exit.
150408 11:46:59 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150408 11:46:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/db1.pid ended
```

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled?

Comment: Just stumbled across this old question... @Alain, could you please add the resolution as a proper answer and mark the question as solved or delete the question?

Comment: Thanks for stopping by @jstarek. I'm looking like crazy all over the page, and I don't see the check mark icon to mark this as resolved. Where is it?

Comment: Hi @Alain, you can just cut the resolution from the text above, create an answer in the form at the bottom of the page from it (yes, you can answer your own questions here) — and *that* will have the check mark icon ;-)

Comment: Hello again @jstarek. I've done it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was with SELinux, I clearly put it in permissive mode, but I never rebooted to changes apply properly. So I checked SELinux current state with `sestatus` and I saw it configured in Permissive mode, but running in Enforcing mode.